# Having problem with file attached to jsp page

Tags: css, spring, jsp

I have a problem attaching the css file to jsp.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/styles.css" type="text/css">
```

I get a warning that there is no such mapping.

WARNING: No mapping for GET /spring-demo-app/css/styles.css

Comment: Please specify what web framework do you use?

Comment: I use spring with jsp